# "uses-material-design: true" not working with other assets in pubspec.yaml

Tags: flutter, dart, yaml, material-design, pubspec

I cannot add any assets like images, fonts, etc. to my project app until I delete/comment this line

```
uses-material-design: true
```

The error

```
Error detected in pubspec.yaml:
Restarted application in ٨ms.
Error on line 25, column 4: Expected a key while parsing a block mapping.
   ╷
25 │    assets:
   │    ^
   ╵
Exception: Please correct the pubspec.yaml file at .\pubspec.yaml
```

Except for this problem, everything is okay in `pubspec.yaml`

```
name: mi_card
description: A new Flutter application.

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
   assets:
    - images/

   fonts:
     - family: Pacifico
       fonts:
         - asset: fonts/Pacifico-Regular.ttf

     - family: Source Sans Pro
       fonts:
        - asset: fonts/SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf
```

but because I need to use material icons, I need to add it with my assets, so How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`pubspec.yaml` is sensitive to indentation.

and your in file after  `uses-material-design: true` is indented by one space , try to remove it and it will work.

copy this and try :

```
name: mi_card
description: A new Flutter application.

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

    # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - images/

  fonts:
    - family: Pacifico
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/Pacifico-Regular.ttf

    - family: Source Sans Pro
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf
```

Comment: Working fine, thank you, please can you refer which line I add more one space because I tried to compare between this and my version, but I cannot found the difference

Comment: its not "addig space" it is removing..
you have to remove two spaces from all lines after uses-material-design: true ,
in other words , the beginning of the lines after  uses-material-design: true should be aligned

Comment: and if that helped pls mark question as answered ;)

Comment: still cant load an image, wasted an hour on this!